# Adding to a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

EDIT: apparently dic.update still works very well in Python, so I've solved my issue. Will leave this up if people look this up in the future.

```
def read_prices_file(filename):
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    items = root.find('Items')
    outer_dict = {}
    middle_dict = {}
    inner_dict = {}
    #outer_dict[inner_dict] = {}
    item_code = ""
    counter = 0
    item = ""
    for element in items.findall('Item'):
        item = element
        for element_2 in item:
            item_code = item.find('ItemCode')
            inner_dict[str(element_2.tag)] = str(element_2.text)
        outer_dict[str(item_code.text)] = inner_dict
        break
    print(outer_dict)

read_prices_file("prices.xml")
```

I want my dictionary to look this like:

```
{ItemCode1 : {Element 1_2 : Element text 1_2, Element 1_3 : Element_text 1,3}, ItemCode2: Element 2_1 : Element text 2_1, ...}
```

But instead it will give the the last one. How do I define where I want to add to the nested dictionary? (Hints are preferable ,not looking for full-blown solutions/code)

Comment: You have a `break` in your second loop. So it will always make one iteration only. Is this the problem?

Comment: `Element 1_3 : Element_text 1,3}` is this a typo in your dictionary? or do you want a list as the value?

Comment: @lucasnadalutti No sorry that shouldn't be there. The XML has over 7000 values, and each of those 7000 has about 5-7 values that causes my IDE to crash

Comment: @depperm What I meant is each outer key will have an inner key and a value if that makes sense